# Life in the UK test

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit, citizenship

I want to pass the Life in the UK test as part of my ILR application.

Can someone please guide me on how/where to start, study and practice the test so that I can successfully pass?

Any help and guidance will be highly appreciated.

Many thanks,
H

Comment: Sadly cannot add an answer but luckily can add a comment. I have studied and passed my Life in the UK test in December 2018. I bought the official book, read it, did the [online unofficial mockup tests](https://lifeintheuktestweb.co.uk/exams) and failed. Then I did them again and again, specially [the 1-15 exams (mockup tests)](https://lifeintheuktestweb.co.uk/exams) for about a week until I answered all the questions 100% correctly every time, booked the official test and passed it in about 6 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As explained, to successfully pass the Life in the UK test, you will need to have good knowledge of the 3rd edition handbook Life in the United Kingdom: A guide for new Residents.

You can buy the book from the recommended GOV.UK site at https://www.tsoshop.co.uk/Society/Life-in-the-UK/

Alternatively, you can read the online version of the book that is available on different websites online. There are various websites on the internet where you can read the online version of the Handbook and practice the tests. Most of them are quite good to practice mock tests that prepare for your final test. I am listing some of them below:

1) https://passlifeinuktest.co.uk/

2) www.thelifeinuktest.co.uk

3) https://www.theuktest.com/

A friend recently used (1) above https://passlifeinuktest.co.uk/  and gave very good reviews.

Once you have read the book and start passing the mock tests on these websites, you are ready for the test!

Good luck with your application!

Best regards,

B